# Facebook fb:fan - Define the count of fans, that are displayed

Tags: facebook, xfbml, facebook-likebox

I'm using the `<fb:fan>` tag of the XFBML, so that I can use a custom style for the like box. The problem with the `<fb:fan>` tag is, that it doesn't automatically calculate the  count of the fans, that are displayed. Is there a way to set this count manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a parameter called `connections` that defines the count of fans are displayed.
e.g. `connections="15"` will display 15 fans.